# how to get the column names of the table sitting in a external stage in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]

the first line works as I have mentioned which columns to display.
but what if I 100 columns and I want to display all the columns, and don't want to write $1,$2.. $100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly list all the columns. There is no equivalent of SELECT * that works with stages